# "Error: forwarding ports: Upgrade request required" Error in helm of a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, helm, rancher, upgrade, centos

I have a kubernetes cluster built using `kubespray` and imported to Rancher.

The nodes are configured with

- CentOS Linux 7 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64
- Docker version : 18.9.5
- Kubelet version : v1.14.1
- Tiller version : v2.14.1 ( got this version from the tiller pod's image `gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.14.1` )

All the tiller resources are working fine:

```
$ kubectl get all -n kube-system | findstr tiller

pod/tiller-deploy-57ff77d846-frtb7             1/1       Running   0          12d

service/tiller-deploy          ClusterIP   10.233.49.112   <none>        44134/TCP                16d

deployment.apps/tiller-deploy             1         1         1            1           16d

replicaset.apps/tiller-deploy-57ff77d846             1         1         1         12d
replicaset.apps/tiller-deploy-69d5cd79bb             0         0         0         16d
```

But when I run the `helm` commands, I am getting this error:

```
$ helm version

Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0", GitCommit:"2e55dbe1fdb5fdb96b75ff144a339489417b146b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: Upgrade request required

$ helm ls

Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: Upgrade request required
```

**I tried:**

- The tiller version is 2.14.1. So, upgraded the helm client to version 2.14.1 from 2.11.0. But that doesn't solves the issue.

Can someone help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58700185/399058):

> Ran into this today when trying to use Garden.io for a cluster running in Jelastic.
>
> Found the solution in [this Github comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1455#issuecomment-533802309):
>
> First acquire a local binary for Tiller (server-version of Helm), either by [compiling](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#from-source-linux-macos) or by [downloading it from the release page](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.14.3).
>
> Then run:
>
> ```
> $ export HELM_HOST=":44134"
> $ tiller -listen ${HELM_HOST} -alsologtostderr >/dev/null 2>&1 &
> ```
>
> This will run a local version of the Kubernetes Helm Server. Now try your original command again, kubectl, that will delegate to this local Helm instead and manage to connect.